# INSERT INTO with CURSOR within a TRIGGER

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, cursor

i'm building a **trigger with a cursor that should give an output in the console when the table is updated or inserted into.** The idea is to count for each brand how many cars are within the table. I've tried many things but it does not seem to work. If I check the simple logic of INSERT INTO statement e.g =

```
SELECT marca, count(*) as cuenta
FROM coches_seg_mano
GROUP BY marca;
```

it would return the sum of the cars under those brands. But now I'm creating a trigger that would give this information to me in a console output everytime I insert or update. I've tried to bring the logic of the query above but it seems it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_mostrarmarcas 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON coches_seg_mano
DECLARE
    CURSOR totalmarcas IS
    SELECT matriculo,COUNT(*) as CUENTA
    FROM coches_seg_mano 
    GROUP BY matriculo;
    vmarca coches_seg_mano.marca%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR fila IN totalmarcas LOOP
    SELECT marca INTO vmarca FROM coches_seg_mano WHERE fila.matriculo=matriculo; 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Para la marca '|| vmarca ||' tenemos '|| fila.cuenta ||' vehiculos');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**The one above DOES gives me an output** but it **DOES NOT** count. It will just give for every entry a 1 and I would see brands reoccur. So not counting the cars there are under each brand.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_mostrarmarcas 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON coches_seg_mano
DECLARE
    CURSOR totalmarcas IS
    SELECT marca,COUNT(*) as CUENTA -- this
    FROM coches_seg_mano 
    GROUP BY marca;
    vmarca coches_seg_mano.marca%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR fila IN totalmarcas LOOP
    SELECT marca INTO vmarca FROM coches_seg_mano WHERE matriculo=matriculo; 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Para la marca '|| vmarca ||' tenemos '|| fila.cuenta ||' vehiculos');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This one would trow error =

```
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T_MOSTRARMARCAS", line 9
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T_MOSTRARMARCAS", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T_MOSTRARMARCAS'
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.ENTRAR_VEHICULO", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 8
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Probably that should be `FROM coches_seg_mano  c WHERE c.matriculo = fila.matriculo`. Or better still, include it as a join in the main cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Such a condition (in `where` clause) is almost always wrong:

```
SELECT marca INTO vmarca FROM coches_seg_mano WHERE matriculo=matriculo;
```

as it means "give me everything", i.e. as if you didn't even use that condition.

---

See whether something like this helps:

```
SQL> create table coches_seg_mano
  2    (marca      varchar2(10),
  3     matriculo  number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into coches_seg_mano values ('BMW', 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into coches_seg_mano values ('Audi', 200);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t_mostramarcas
  2    after insert or update on coches_seg_mano
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select marca, count(*) as cuenta
  5                  from coches_seg_mano
  6                  group by marca
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line('Marca = ' || cur_r.marca ||
 10                           ', cuenta = ' || cur_r.cuenta);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> insert into coches_seg_mano values ('BMW', 300);
Marca = BMW, cuenta = 2
Marca = Audi, cuenta = 1

1 row created.

SQL> insert into coches_seg_mano
  2    select 'BMW', 400 from dual union all
  3    select 'Mercedes', 500 from dual;
Marca = BMW, cuenta = 3
Marca = Mercedes, cuenta = 1
Marca = Audi, cuenta = 1

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

That *works*, kind of ... It's just that I don't understand the purpose of such a trigger. You'll see the output only if **you** run the insert. End users, if they use - for example - Oracle Forms or Apex application - won't see anything. Even if someone else runs an INSERT in their own SQL*Plus session, you won't see anything (as the result will be displayed on *their* screen, not yours).

Comment: Thanks so much! I've got it to work!!!!!! I didn't know you could create a select statement between brackets within the FOR loop. I still have a lot to learn but thank you so much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `SELECT` in the second trigger which doesn't work is wrong because it returns multiple rows since `matriculo=matriculo` is always true like e.g. 1=1.

```
SELECT marca INTO vmarca FROM coches_seg_mano WHERE matriculo=matriculo;
```

Try to change the where clause.